# Should the "connection" argument of doWork() be closed?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, c3p0

I am using a C3P0 Connection Pool with Hibernate to execute some JDBC operations. However, I am getting a "Closed Connection" (SQL Error: 17008, SQLState: null) error after some time of usage.

I am using the [org.hibernate.jdbc.Work](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/jdbc/Work.html) interface to perform my operations:

```
public class ClassThatDoesWork implements Work {

    @Override
    public void execute(final Connection connection)
            throws SQLException {

        doSomeWork();
        //should connection be closed here?
    }
}
```

My question is: should the `connection` object passed as an argument to the `execute()` method be closed at the end of that method or Hibernate takes care for that automatically?

EDIT
These are the Hibernate and c3p0 parameters used:

```
hibernate.connection.driver_class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
hibernate.connection.pool_size=10
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.show_sql=false
acquireIncrement=3
acquireRetryDelay=500
acquireRetryAttempts=5
breakAfterAcquireFailure=false
checkoutTimeout=0
connectionTesterClassName=com.mchange.v2.impl.DefaultConnectionTester
debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces=false
dataSourceName=irrelevantDB
identityToken=irrelevantDB
idleConnectionTestPeriod=0
initialPoolSize=3
maxConnectionAge=0
maxIdleTime=7200
maxIdleTimeExcessConnections=0
maxPoolSize=20
maxStatements=50
maxStatementsPerConnection=0
minPoolSize=5
numHelperThreads=3
propertyCycle=0
testConnectionOnCheckin=false
testConnectionOnCheckout=true
unreturnedConnectionTimeout=0
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20
hibernate.c3p0.timeout=10
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50
```

Comment: Every time I use C3P0, its settings are specified without the hibernate prefix. I.e. c3p0.min_size=5 instead of hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5. Pls also try the c3p0.idle_test_period setting as per my answer.

Comment: Please see [this part of the c3p0 documentation](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific). Properties are indeed prefixed with "hibernate.c3p0". I will get back once I try the c3p0.idle_test_period setting.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out that we were not using C3P0 at all, as it was not correctly picked up as a dependency, so this will probably fix the "Connection Closed" problem, regardless of the c3p0.idle_test_period property. However, I am still interested if the `connection` object should be maintained by my code or Hibernate takes care for it automatically.

Comment: It is passed in as a method argument by Hibernate, and thus should not be tempted (e.g. closed) inside the method -- this is Hibernate's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks! Please state this in your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The database connection is passed in as a method argument by Hibernate, and thus should not be tampered with (e.g. closed) inside the method -- this is Hibernate's responsibility.